# Convert the contents of a cell array into a single matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to convert the cell (csi) whose dimensions are 2x3x30 complex double into a matrix (a1) with the same dimension and data type.
I used this code:

```
a1 = cell2mat(csi)
```

but an error appeared :

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
Error in cell2mat (line 42)
cellclass = class(c{1});
```

Kindly, see the attached picture of my matlab work window.
[matlab work window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yz1V.png)
Please could you tell me why this error is appearing? what I need to do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to do {} indexing for something that isn't a cell array.  In this case, csi is *already* a normal 2x3x30 complex double array, as shown in your workspace window.  Perhaps you mean that you want to do something like reshape the array into something other than 2x3x30?